# Rails 4 : uninitialized constant upon app initialize - lib loading issue in staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am running rake db:setup in staging environment

```
bundle exec rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=staging
```

my config/environments/staging.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
    ..
    config.eager_load = true
    ..
end
```

I get this error during app initialization :

```
: uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::MyModule
 ../my_test/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:4:in `<module:ApplicationHelper>'
```

/app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include MyModule::Ditto::Base
  include MyModule::Ditto::MyHelper
  ..
end
```

and the lib files are :

```
/lib/misc/my_module/ditto/base.rb
module MyModule
    module Ditto
        module Base
        …
        end
    end
end

/lib/misc/my_module/ditto/my_helper.rb
module MyModule
    module Ditto
        module SliderHelpers
        …
        end
   end
end
```

I guess the modules in the lib are not autoloaded  .. ( everything run well in development environment as all lib 'require' are hard-coded ..
what should I add to get it running in staging/prod environment ?

thanks for your lights ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` to `config/application.rb`

Comment: by default `lib` folder in `Rails.root` dir not in `app/`.

Comment: thanks Andrey.. as my lib structure is more complex , I resolved to require the modules in initialisers ..  however which is very strange , the array is not always the same order , and sometime the Base module doesn't come first leading to uninitialized constant BaseView ...
Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/calendars/lib/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
the BaseView is the first class , others are subclasses... any idea ?